# Segfault when inserting a node into a doubly list

Tags: c

```
void ins_after(struct node *node, struct node *new_node)
{
    new_node -> next = node -> next; 
    node -> next = new_node; 
    new_node -> next -> prev = new_node;
    new_node -> prev = node;
}
```

The code above gives a segfault when I try to insert a node into a doubly list. Any idea why? =/

Comment: One of the involved pointers is a null pointer?

Answer (score 2):

You must `NULL`-check the pointers, consider what happens if the `node` is at the beginning or end of the list, as often happens when building a list by repeated append.

A "lonely" list item will typically have both `prev` and `next` equal to `NULL`.

Comment: Oh gosh I just got that, my logic makes sense but it only works if there is no NULL XD thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Handle conditions when your list contains

1. Nothing ( when node is `NULL`)
2. only one node where nodes `prev` and `next` points to `NULL`